# Value of type String cannot be converted to 1 dimensional array of Byte

Tags: vb.net, tableadapter

Here is the declaration:

```
Public Class Client
Public Property Address() As String
    Get
        Return mAddress

    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mAddress = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property City() As String
    Get
        Return mCity

    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mCity = value
    End Set
End Property
end sub
```

And the ERROR lies in here:

```
Public Function InsertClientRecordToDb(ByVal cli As Client) As Boolean
        Dim retVal As Boolean
        Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet("dataSet")
        dataSet.EnforceConstraints = False
        'create table adapter object
        Dim ClientTblAdapter As New CaseStudyDBDataSetTableAdapters.Client_TableTableAdapter

    'check db connection
    If ClientTblAdapter.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        ClientTblAdapter.Connection.Open()
    End If

    'perform(insert)
    If ClientTblAdapter.InsertClientRecord(cli.Clientcode, cli.Clientname, cli.Address, cli.City, cli.Contactperson, cli.Contactnumber) > 0 Then
        retVal = True
    End If**

    Return retVal
End Function
```

The "cli.Address" and "cli.City" was underlined saying:

> Value of type String cannot be converted to 1 dimensional array of Byte

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: How is InsertClientRecord defined?

Answer (score 1):

For the error it seems like you are trying to assign string to `Byte()`

Something like :

```
Dim bArr As Byte() = "hello world!"
```

which is wrong, to convert string to `Byte()` **you need to use the `Encoding` class**

```
Dim bArr As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hello world!")
```